# .htaccess code to ban some ip and redirect to other subdomain

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess

i need .htaccess code to redirect and ban ip's ,i mean if i try to load **www.site.com** with **123.456.789.101** ip address allow me, but if someone else try to load ,redirect them to other subdomain like **sub.site.com** , i write below code but dont work correctly.

```
<Limit GET POST PUT> Order Deny,Allow
 Deny from all
 Allow from 123.456.789.101
</Limit>
301 redirect / http://new.site.com
<Files otherpage.html>
 Order Allow,Deny
 Allow from all
</Files>
```

please help , Tank You

Answer (score 1):

Replace your `Limit` block and `301 redirect` with this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.456\.789\.101$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://new.site.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

So that it's *above* your `Files` block (though I'm not sure why you'd need that)

Comment: @ppmblackhat As far as answering your question, this is the "full code"